# What made Jesse & the Rippers separate?

Tags: full-house

In *Full House*, I don't know in what season or episode, there was a scene with uncle Jesse and his band called "Jesse & the Rippers". One day when they were doing rehearsal they were having an argument with Jesse and after that Rippers left Jesse. So my question is, what is the reason, what caused the separation of Jesse & the Rippers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Full House Wikia](http://fullhouse.wikia.com/wiki/Jesse_and_the_Rippers), he's kicked out due to his commitment to his family.

In season 8, episode 1, it opens with Jesse and his band rehearsing, but he keeps getting interrupted, first by Nicky and Alex, then by Stephanie asking him what kind of "swizzle sticks" he wants for the club.  Then Joey comes down, and says they need to be down at the radio station, so Jesse calls off the bands practice.  This causes the band members to step and and inform Jesse that they have taken a vote and decided they don't want him to be part of the band anymore, that he has too many commitments outside of the band and he just isn't committed like he used to be.

> After Jesse is kicked out of the band for his commitment to his family, he is replaced by former Brady Bunch star Barry Williams (and the band is renamed Barry and the Rippers). They achieved a hit song "April Girls", which is loved by everyone in the Tanner household, much to Jesse's chagrin. Jesse later forms a new band called Hot Daddy and the Monkey Puppets.